# change date format for the whole column in data table without for each

Tags: c#, vb.net, date, datatable, format

How to change the date format for the whole column in the data table in VB.NET or C#? (Without using for each)

this helps me to do on a single cell:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(row("columnName").ToString,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Thanks,
Sivan

Comment: ```myTable.Columns["columnName"].Convert(
    val => DateTime.Parse(val.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));```

Comment: What is the Data Type of `columnName`? Is it string? Then change it to DateTime. Then format the output, if needed, when you present the data in the UI.

Comment: Yiou column is a DateTime so there is no need to format.  When you display the data like in a DataGridView format the column of the DGV.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. `DateTime` values are just numbers. They are an offset from a specific moment in time. They have no format. Format is only an issue when converting a `DateTime` value to a `String` for display, so that is where/when you should consider format. The fact that you think they are in the wrong format to begin with suggests that you are displaying them somehow so maybe you should explain where that is and we can explain how to format as you desire at that point.

Answer (score 0):

this answer for help you to format all rows in specific columns

**dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
dataGridView1.Columns("columnName").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"**